# What I am missing in this macro?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a shortened version, but the intent is it looks if the value of `txtcustomer` does exists in the `customerref` list, if not then it matches only `txtmodel` and `txtbounce` to their respective cells. If the value does exist on the list then it matches `txtmodel`, `txtbounce` and `txtcustomer` to their respective cells.

It mostly works but the "if value exists" part is putting all values in the list together rather keeping those values segregated to their own ranges. It doesn't seem to be matching all three criteria though that section does work correctly if that is the only bit of code.

```vb
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
    Dim nextBlankCell As Range
    Dim customerRef As Range
    Set customerRef = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ref").Range("K2:K12")

    If Not customerRef.Find(TravelerForm.txtCustomer.Value) Is Nothing Then
        If ws.Cells(12, 1) = "" Or (ws.Cells(12, 1) = TravelerForm.txtModel.Value And ws.Cells(10, 3) = TravelerForm.txtBounce.Value) Then
            Set nextBlankCell = ws.Range("A13:A54").Find("", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not nextBlankCell Is Nothing Then
                nextBlankCell.Value = TravelerForm.txtSerial.Value
                nextBlankCell.Select
            Else
                MsgBox "No blank cells found in range A13:A54"
            End If
        ElseIf ws.Cells(12, 7) = "" Or (ws.Cells(12, 7) = TravelerForm.txtModel.Value And ws.Cells(10, 9) = TravelerForm.txtBounce.Value) Then
            Set nextBlankCell = ws.Range("G13:G54").Find("", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not nextBlankCell Is Nothing Then
                nextBlankCell.Value = TravelerForm.txtSerial.Value
                nextBlankCell.Select
            Else
                MsgBox "No blank cells found in range G13:G54"
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If ws.Cells(12, 1) = "" Or (ws.Cells(12, 1) = TravelerForm.txtModel.Value And ws.Cells(10, 3) = TravelerForm.txtBounce.Value And ws.Cells(12, 4) = TravelerForm.txtCustomer.Value) Then
            Set nextBlankCell = ws.Range("A13:A54").Find("", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not nextBlankCell Is Nothing Then
                nextBlankCell.Value = TravelerForm.txtSerial.Value
                nextBlankCell.Select
            Else
                MsgBox "No blank cells found in range A13:A54"
            End If
        ElseIf ws.Cells(12, 7) = "" Or (ws.Cells(12, 7) = TravelerForm.txtModel.Value And ws.Cells(10, 9) = TravelerForm.txtBounce.Value And ws.Cells(12, 10) = TravelerForm.txtCustomer.Value) Then
            Set nextBlankCell = ws.Range("G13:G54").Find("", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not nextBlankCell Is Nothing Then
                nextBlankCell.Value = TravelerForm.txtSerial.Value
                nextBlankCell.Select
            Else
            MsgBox "No blank cells found in range G13:G54"
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: When using something like `If A Or B And C And D Then` it's best to use parentheses to be explicit about exactly where that `Or` applies: eg `If (A Or B) And C And D Then`

Comment: Just curious, assume that txtcustomer does exists in the customerref.  ws.Cells(12, 1), ws.Cells(12, 7), ws.Cells(13, 1), ws.Cells(13, 7) value are all blank. What is the expected result after running the sub ?

Comment: Tim- Thanks for your quick reply, I did try your suggestion, unfortunately it provided the same results. I did come up with a solution that seems to be working. I changed the "If not on list" to instead of only matching txtModel and txtBounce it also does a check to make sure the txtCustomer is not on the Ref list.

Comment: changed Line from:  If ws.Cells(12, 1) = "" Or (ws.Cells(12, 1) = TravelerForm.txtModel.Value And ws.Cells(10, 3) = TravelerForm.txtBounce.Value) Then                                                                                                                                   To: If ws.Cells(12, 1) = "" Or (ws.Cells(12, 1) = TravelerForm.txtModel.Value And ws.Cells(10, 3) = TravelerForm.txtBounce.Value And IsError(Application.match(ws.Cells(12, 4), customerRef, 0))) Then

Comment: Karma- the desired outcome is that any customer on the list is segregated to its own range by model and bounce, any customer not on the list can be grouped together but still separated by model and bounce